# Migrating mapped drives to another computer

Tags: windows, network-shares

What is the easiest way to copy mapped network drives from one Windows PC to another Windows PC? Both PCs are on the same network.

I was thinking about creating a script to do it, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution.

Apparently there's a registry key which stores them in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network`

If you export it, and import it on the other pc, you get the same mapped drives.